# Javascript hide search results when searchbar is empty

Tags: javascript, html, search, hide

I created a search function for a shop website. Currently when I run the html, the search results are shown from the begining. The mechanism of wrtiting letters and the results are only those that fit, works perfectly. I am just wondering how I can hide the search results from the begining and only show them when i click into the search box or when i write my first letter into it.

```
<body style="background-color: #F3F3F3;">
    
<div class="input-wrapper">
            <div class="fa fa-search"></div>
            <input class="suche" type="search" placeholder="Search.." id="search-item" onkeyup="search()" >
    </div>   

    <div class="ProdukteListe" id="ProdukteListe">

        <div class="ProduktName">
            <img src="hoodiefrontlogo.png" alt="">
            <div class= "ProduktDetails">
                <h2>ProduktName</h2>
                <h3>Preis</h3>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="ProduktName">
            <img src="hoodieback.png" alt="">
            <div class=" ProduktDetails ">
                <h2>ProduktName</h2>
                <h3>Preis</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ProduktName">
            <img src="" alt="">
            <div class=" ProduktDetails ">
                <h2>ProduktName2</h2>
                <h3>Preis</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

---

```
const search = () =>{ const searchbox = document.getElementById("search-item").value.toUpperCase(); 
const storeitems = document.getElementById("ProdukteListe") 
const product = document.querySelectorAll(".ProduktName") 
const pname = storeitems.getElementsByTagName("h2")

for(var i=0; i < pname.length; i++){

    let match = product[i].getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];

    
    if(match){
        let textvalue = match.textContent || match.innerHTML

        if(textvalue.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchbox) > - 1){
            product[i].style.display = "";

        }else{
            product[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to write a if into the script but it cant work because the script only executes when the first letter is typed. But the hiding i want has to be the default before that.

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) Have you thought about creating a class, such as `.none { display: none}`, adding it to your result list, and then toggling it on and off (`elem.classList.toggle('none')`, based on the number of non-empty characters in the searchbox? 2) Which event listeners are you currently using to trigger the searchbox filtering? 3) Have you considered using AJAX / XHR to populate the search box, instead of loading everything at once?

Answer (score 0):

You can just set `display: none` for div ProdukteListe and then set its display to block inside your search function

```
const search = () =>{
    document.getElementById("ProdukteListe").style.display = "block";
...
}
```

Comment: You mean setting display: none in my css right? If I do this and add the .style.display = "block"; the results are still shown and even wont go away if I type. When I remove the .style.display = "block";, nothing changes to the version without display = none